# how to make text wrap when the length of text over length of div?

Tags: html, css

I need to append text user entered into a fixed width and height div. I set the div overflow:auto, but I only want to show vertical scrollbar, don't want to see the horizontal one. How to make the text wrap automatically to fix the width of div?

```
<script>
function Send(){
    var text=$("[id$='Text1']").val();
    $('#contentDIV').append("me:    "+text+"<br />");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3CQmP/

Comment: overflow-y is not known as a property name. It does not work,man

Comment: @Steven Zack i just added a link to the online demo check it out

Comment: Yea, I know, it weird. But after add this property into div style, the horizontal scrollbar still shows when the text length over div width

Comment: @amosrivera: The text will wrap regardless. `overflow-y:auto;` just adds a scrollbar so that height doesn't change.

Comment: @Mrchief, the problem is the text does not wrap

Comment: Check if white-space property isn't "nowrap" or if spaces are non-breakables spaces (&nbsp;)

Comment: If you have a single sequential series of characters without white space, it won't wrap.  I don't think there is anything you can do about that, but that's not typical of natural languages.

Answer (score 1):

The text will wrap unless a **word** is longer than your `div` can content. In this case you just have [word-break](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) (CSS3).